# Merging 3 collections to return one object per row

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, eloquent, vuejs2

I'm returning a town, state and country to a Vue 2 autocomplete field using axios. The fields for the queries are all in the same table; locations. If I return just the town, the field works great but there are plenty of towns in the world with the same name so I want to return the state/region and country the town is in along with it. The problem I have is getting my controller to output an object for the town, state and country instead of merging them into separate objects.

I've tried using the merge, put and combine methods that Eloquent provides. Merge and put will give me an array of 6 objects with my test data which is Birmingham as there's one in West Midlands, England and one in Alabama, USA. Objects 0 and 1 have the town id, town name and parent id, 2 and 3 have the state id etc and 4 and 5 have the country id etc. Searched Google and here for answers with most saying merge but it won't actually put each separate collection into one object.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use \App\Location;

class AjaxLocationsController extends Controller {
public function index(Request $request) {
$searchquery = $request->searchquery;
$states = collect();
$countries = collect();
$all_details = collect();

    $locations = Location::select('id', 'location', 'parent_id')
    ->where([['id', '>', 4351], ['location', 'like', '%' . $searchquery . '%']])
    ->orderBy('location')
    ->get();

    foreach($locations as $location)
    {

        $state = Location::select('id as state_id', 'location as state', 'parent_id as state_parent_id')
        ->where('id', '=', $location->parent_id)
        ->get();

        $states->push($state);
    }

    $states = $states->flatten();

    foreach($states as $state)
    {
        $country = Location::select('id as country_id', 'location as country')
        ->where('id', '=', $state->state_parent_id)
        ->get();

        $countries->push($country);
    }

    $countries = $countries->flatten();

    $all_details = $all_details->merge($locations);
    $all_details = $all_details->merge($states);
    $all_details = $all_details->merge($countries);
    $all_details = $all_details->flatten();

    return $all_details;
}
```

}

I would've expected this to be pretty easy to do and although I'm pretty new to Laravel (5.8), I've had a lot of experience using PHP arrays. I'm thinking I must be missing something as I've been at this all day!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't help with the PHP but it wouldn't be difficult to just return multiple objects/ multiple arrays and then display them with slots in any manner you want. You would need to pair them but if you have say a large object  containing a number of smaller objects then that would work. Or parallel arrays that the index's match.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Michael. This is pretty much what I'm trying to achieve but in an Eloquent (ie Laravel) way.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out what I would say is more of a non-Eloquent way to do it but I'll post my code here hoping it will help other people with the same type of problem. The ajax response is pretty fast (around 100ms) so I'm quite happy with the result. If anyone else has a better (more Eloquent) solution, please post an answer here. Cheers!

Ajax Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use \App\Location;

class AjaxLocationsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
    $searchquery = $request->searchquery;
    $states = collect();
    $countries = collect();
    $all_details = collect();
    $counter = 0;

    $locations = Location::select('id', 'location', 'parent_id')
    ->where([['id', '>', 4351], ['location', 'like', '%' . $searchquery . '%']])
    ->orderBy('location')
    ->get();

    foreach ($locations as $location)
    {
        $state = Location::select('id as state_id', 'location as state', 'parent_id as state_parent_id')
        ->where('id', '=', $location->parent_id)
        ->get();

        $states->push($state);
    }

    $states = $states->flatten();

    foreach ($states as $state)
    {
        $country = Location::select('id as country_id', 'location as country')
        ->where('id', '=', $state->state_parent_id)
        ->get();

        $countries->push($country);
    }

    $countries = $countries->flatten();

    foreach ($locations as $location)
    {
        $full_location = collect([
            'id' => $location->id,
            'location' => $location->location,
            'parent_id' => $location->parent_id,
            'state_id' => $states[$counter]['state_id'],
            'state' => $states[$counter]['state'],
            'state_parent_id' => $states[$counter]['state_parent_id'],
            'country_id' => $countries[$counter]['country_id'],
            'country' => $countries[$counter]['country'],
        ]);

        $all_details = $all_details->push($full_location);
        $counter++;
    }

    return $all_details;
}
}

Vue Component

<template>
<div>
    <label for="searchquery">Town</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="searchquery" v-on:keyup="getLocations" class="form- 
control">
    <div class="panel-footer" v-if="data_results.length">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <a href="#" @click="setLocation(result)" class="list-group-item list- 
group-item-action" v-for="result in data_results" :key="result.id">{{ result.location 
}}, {{ result.state }}, {{ result.country }}</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
    return {
        searchquery: '',
        data_results: []
    }
},
methods: {
    getLocations() {
        this.data_results = [];
        if (this.searchquery.length > 1) {
            axios.get('/get-locations', { params: { searchquery: this.searchquery } })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.data_results = response.data;
                });
        }
    },
    setLocation(result) {
        this.searchquery = result.location + ', ' + result.state + ', ' + result.country;
        this.data_results = [];
    }
},
}
</script>
```

[image: Output in JSON]

[image: Output on website]